# Is there any good boolean query parser for ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any library in ElasticSearch or other open-source, that transforms the boolean query into a ElasticSearch query?

With the typical boolean query expressions (AND, OR, "", *, ?) to transform into the "json" query for ElasticSearch and create the "musts", "shoulds", etc...

I mean, for example, to transform this:

```
(city = 'New York' AND state = 'NY') AND ((businessName='Java' and businessName='Shop') OR (category='Java' and category = 'Shop'))
```

into this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "city": "New york"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "state": "NY"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "businessName": "Java"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "businessName": "Shop"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "category": "Java"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "category": "Shop"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Python library called [luqum](https://github.com/jurismarches/luqum) that does exactly what you need.

That library will parse the Lucene expression into an abstract syntax tree. You can then use that tree and [generate the Elasticsearch JSON DSL equivalent query](https://luqum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#transforming-to-elastic-query).

Comment: PERFECT ! Thank you !